# Build Error in Unity3d: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. ':launcher:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

Having this error after adding Firebase Cloud functionality in my Unity3d project.

Anyone having the same issue?

we have tried "flutter doctor --android-licenses" like suggested in
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30573

Nothing works so far.

Following are the entire error messages.

================================================

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.19f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleDebug"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':launcher:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Cannot set the value of read-only property 'class' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultExcludeRule.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8
]
exit code: 1

UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <c8b3b39837d14a59b516963b78bf9032>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <97ba64834c8f4edc84e3d8e30b04f122>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Answer (score 3):

After the days of tormenting ( Not hours ), we could build eventually. But following is a surprising fact we found. In Unity3d, the three google packages, firebase, google-signin, and googleMobileAds are having un-resolvable dependency problems and consequently we couldn't build successfully. So at the end of all combinatorial trials we decided to eliminate googleMobileAds from our project, then we could finally build for "Android" successfully.

We experimented with an empty project without having any our code. The result was the same. Failed. Upper mentioned packages were failed to build with an empty unitypackage in an empty scene.

I will give you the detailed versions of each packages.

Unity3d ( Unity 2020.3.19f1)

firebase_unity_sdk.8.6.2

google-signin-plugin-1.0.4

GoogleMobileAds-v6.1.2

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue, and the reason was using gradle version 32.0.0.

Please check this link form unity issuetracker:

- https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-android-build-fails-when-targeting-sdk-31-and-using-build-tools-31-dot-0-0

So i solved it by uninstalling build-tools 32.0.0 and using 30.0.2 instead (from sdk manager).

[Android sdk build tools] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo6SB.png